# Moving a float towards another float by a specified amount

Tags: floating-point, target

I have a **current** value that i want to move towards a **target** by an **amount**.
If the value overshoots the target I want it to clamp.

A standard use for this function would be moving an object towards a destination every frame in pretty much any game engine.

I have my own implementation below, but was wondering if there was something cleaner.

```
public static float MoveTowards(float orig, float target, float amount)
{
    //moves orig towards target by amount. Clamps to target if overshot.
    float result = orig;
    if (orig < target) {
        result = orig+amount;
        if (result > target) {
            result = target;
        }
    } else if (orig > target) {
        result = orig - amount;
        if (result < target) {
            result = target;
        }
    } else {
        result = target;
    }
    return result;

}
```

Answers in any language are fine, though hopefully something like java/C#/python etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (orig < target)
    result = min(orig+amount, target)
else if (orig > target)
    result = max(orig-amount, target)
else
    result = target
```

Comment: Brilliant! Totally forgot about min/max for clamping

Answer (score 1):

You could use min and max as correctly suggested by mdebeus.
But beware: if amount is too small w.r.t. orig magnitude, then orig+amount might == orig and fail to advance.

You might want to call nextafter to mitigate this possible issue, like

```
result = min( max(orig+amount,nextafter(orig,target)) , target )
```